# Group literal string in htaccess regex pattern

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need to rewrite URLs similar to

```
/b
```

to

```
/img/b.png
```

as well as URLs similar to

```
/b_c
```

to

```
/img/b_c.png
```

I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^b(?:/_c/)$     /img/$1.png
```

Which works for the first case but not the second (it is not matching "_c" and grouping it).

I need the literal string "_c" to be grouped and placed in the rewritten URL.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `RewriteRule ^(b(_c)?)$ /img/$1.png`.

This makes `$1` the entire bracket backreference, and makes the `_c` optional, but it must be all there (you can't have `b_` matching - though it can match if you want).